# Default .NET Runtime Version

Tags: .net

I have a few .NET versions under C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\

What system variable controls what gets run by default??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "System" variable for this.

Your application (.Net assembly) is compiled for certain framework and that framework is then used when you execute it.

Answer (score 3):

It's the individual applications that determine on which version of the .NET framework it will run.

If you're talking about ASP.NET applications, the version it will run on is set in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The application itself comes with a manifest that tells your system what version of the framework it is targetting at.

Answer (score 0):

Your application will determine to use which of them